# Website Text Search with Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an android app for fun, I am able to import the web search box into the app, but what I would like to do, is to have the search restricted to given website(s). So, I would like for the user to be able to enter a string into the text box, and for the search engine to search the given website(s), that is programmed into the script, and return posts associated with the string.

Can someone either explain or reference material the will explain how to do this, or at least give me the name of this process so I could do research myself?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [getStringExtra intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29), then what you can do is you can store the search query in a String.  Once you get this, you can use HttpGet() where you can specify the website you want to search along with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in Android but if there is no other way in API, you can try to add a prefix to every search query such as "site:siteone.com || site:sitetwo.com " etc. this will force google to search only on siteone.com and sitetwo.com.

But I think there must be a better way.